# Permission denied when trying to use Python in Windows PowerShell, even with admin privileges

Tags: python, windows, powershell, numpy, pip

I'm having an issue with running Python3 and pip. I get a permission denied response when trying the execute these programs. This happens even when I run PowerShell with administrator privileges.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K11F3.png
To be clear, I have also tried `python3 -m pip install numpy` and I get the same error.

What could be causing this issue and how can I fix this?

Thank you!

Edit: I've tried running other applications (such as Skype) from the command line and it shows the same error, leading me to believe that this is is something I need to implement a general fix in Windows.

Comment: Post error diagnostics as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Python installation folder's security permissions by:

1. Open a Python shell
2. Go to task manager
3. Find the python process
4. Right-click and open location
5. The folder will open in explorer, go up a directory
6. Right-click the folder and select properties
7. Click the security tab and hit 'edit'
8. Add everyone and give them permission to Read and Write.
9. Save your changes

If you open `cmd` as admin; then you can do the following:

If Python is set in your `PATH`, then:

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: HI, I've implemented the steps that you suggested, but I am still getting the same error. I've tried restarting my pc as well. Just to make sure, the folder I've added the permissions to is "Python39" which contains within it the Python executable.

Comment: @treks2448 Check `gcm python` to verify which python executable is being used

Comment: I've checked the executable: C:\Users\igorg\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe. I'm not sure what I can do with this; the permissions seem fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue. I had to add the python directory to the system variable path.